# How to transfer thousands of dollars ($7000) to a friend?

Tags: united-states, banking, money-transfer, wire-transfer

If a friend wants to transfer $7000 to me, what is the best way to do it, especially if we don't share the same banks? We could do wire transfer, but that comes with its own fees. Could we also do direct deposit? Paypal doesn't allow such large lump sum transfers.

This would be US-to-US transfer.

Comment: What's the priority?  Does the funds need to get there quickly or cheaply?

Comment: Cheaply, preferably

Comment: What's wrong with a personal check?

Comment: **Caution** if your "friend" wants you to either refund or send some of the money somewhere else.  There is a scam, where the incoming money appears to arrive in some form -- but never really arrives (i.e. bad check, chargeback, "I did send it, why are you lying about it? I thought I could trust you")-- and so the victim sends outgoing money which is gone.

Comment: Use bitcoin almost free transaction fee

Answer (score 11):

The simplest thing to do is still one of the oldest: Write a check.  If you don't have a checking account, you can still probably enter the payment in your bank's online bill pay - In this case they will send him a paper check.

There's an irrational desire these days to avoid checks at all costs, which I don't understand.  There's a time and place for electronic transfers and there's no doubt they're often very useful.  This is probably not one of those cases, however, since neither you nor your friend are set up for it.

Comment: This is not a bill payment it is simply an EFT (Electronic Funds Transfer).

Comment: @GeorgeRenous You can use "bill payment" to pay individuals. Despite the name, there's no need for an actual "bill" to be issued. The second part of your comment I don't understand. There's no EFT involved in my answer or necessarily in the question. (EFT is one way that you might consider transferring money, but it's not a requirement and not what I suggested.)

Comment: It's not a particularly irrational desire to avoid the annoyance of writing a check. I don't even *have* any checks - I'd have to go buy some first. 

That said, I do have a checking account, but I still occasionally use the method described in your second sentence, and yes, that is exactly what happens, the bank mails a check so I don't have to.

Comment: @neminem The OP was considering a wire transfer for $7k. That won't be less hassle than a check. Totally agree with your sentiment in most cases, but the check still has its place and probably will for a while longer before it completely goes the way of the dinasour.

Comment: Buy cheques? doesn't your bank provide a cheque book

Comment: @Pepone Given the spelling "cheques" I guess we can assume you're not from the US. :)  It's not common for US banks to provide free checkbooks, no. It's sometimes a perk for customers with larger balances and maybe some specific banks do it for everyone, but it's definitely not universal. That being said, I would think everyone with a checking account should have a book even if they have to pay and don't use it often.  But kids these days!  Always with the computer.

Comment: In Australia you need a Biller Id Number and a Bill Reference Number to make an electronic bill payment. These are usually made to companies that are billing you for goods or services. To make an online transfer to another account whether your own or someone else's from another bank you make an EFT from your account to theirs. And banks here offer their customers with chequing accounts free cheque books.

Comment: @Victor That's interesting. I've never heard of that. In this case the question specifies US->US though. For sure you can do an "online bill pay" to an individual here. I've both made and received money this way. (The check comes with text like "Please accept this payment from our mutual customer" which is kind of funny when it's your buddy paying for something personal.) Conversely, and EFT between personal accounts is not so easy, especially when the accounts are owned by different people. There's some support but not widespread yet.

Comment: Sounds like the banks in the US haven't arrived into the 21st century yet, banking is so easy everywhere else and a lot cheaper too.

Answer (score 1):

He can do an internet bank transfer from his/her account to yours, a direct deposit at a branch of your bank, use PayPal, which should allow such an amount or similar methods.

$7000 is not considered a large amount these days and should be quite easy to execute in a number of ways.

Comment: Would Internet bank transfer come with fees if done from one bank to another?

Comment: That depends on the bank and the account. I don't pay any fees for transfers with my account.

Answer (score 0):

As others say, a check is the best answer here (or using online bill pay to have your bank mail a check), but you could also look into Zelle. It's an electronic money transfer service similar to PayPal, but owned by and integrated with many US financial institutions. Each bank sets [different sending limits](https://www.mybanktracker.com/checking/faq/zelle-pay-limits-274406), but some would allow sending $7000 if you split the amount into two or three smaller transactions sent over the course of several days.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like, you could just withdraw the $7000 in cash and hand it to your friend physically. Of course the dangers are quite clear, but it is the most ensured way to give your friend the money with no fees.

However, I would still not recommend that. $7000 is a lot of money to carry around in cash, and comes with its own concerns. I would recommend what the rest say, a simple cheque.